# Selecting a certain value with php from SQL query

Tags: php, sql

```
$slider = tep_db_query("select slider_config_value, slider_config_id from " . TABLE_SLIDER_CONFIG . " ");
while ($theslider = tep_db_fetch_array($slider)) {
$autoStart = $theslider['slider_config_value'];
}
```

What I'm trying to do is select the slider_config_value for certain slider_config_id with code as short as possible. Because I know I could use 'where slider_config_id = ...' but I'd have to have a query for each of em.

What I need is someting like

```
$autoStart = $theslider['slider_config_value', '1'];
$loop = $theslider['slider_config_value', '22'];
$margin = $theslider['slider_config_value', '4'];
etc.
```

I have been trying to find a solution, but haven't dealt with this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$slider = tep_db_query("select slider_config_value, slider_config_id from " . TABLE_SLIDER_CONFIG . " ");
$slider_configs = array();
while ($theslider = tep_db_fetch_array($slider)) {
    $slider_configs[$theslider['slider_config_id']] = $theslider['slider_config_value'];
}
$autoStart = $slider_configs[1];
$loop = $slider_configs[22];
$margin = $slider_configs[4];
```